# Javascript Display one image per minute depending on time of the day

Tags: javascript, image, clock

I am a newbie in JavaScript. I am trying to create a javascript that displays one single, different photo every minute of the day.

I am filling up a folder with 1440 images (one for each minute). The files are named accordingly (ie: for 2:45 the image will be `0245.jpg`).

What I am doing so far is created a clock that displays time, but I need to use those strings to request a new object with that name. I have tried a few options, but none of them work. Probably something simple for advanced guys, but I just can't make it work.
This is what I 've tried so far (many versions):

```
*function date_time(id)
{
        date = new Date;
        year = date.getFullYear();
        month = date.getMonth();
        months = new Array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');
        d = date.getDate();
        day = date.getDay();
        days = new Array('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday');
        h = date.getHours();
        if(h<10)
        {
                h = "0"+h;
        }
        m = date.getMinutes();
        if(m<10)
        {
                m = "0"+m;
        }
        s = date.getSeconds();
        if(s<10)
        {
                s = "0"+s;
        }
        result = ''+days[day]+' '+months[month]+' '+d+' '+year+' '+h+':'+m;
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = result;
        setTimeout('date_time("'+id+'");','60000');
        return true;
}
setInterval(function() {
    var minutePhotoElement = document.getElementById('minutePhoto');
    minutePhoto.src = "'img/('result').jpg'";
}, 60000);
//-->*
```

Comment: Can you post the code for what you've tried?

Comment: And where is the code?

Comment: Ok, I have updated the original post with the code I'm working on right now... It has been changed many, many times.

Answer (score 1):

Without your code it's difficult to guess what fits better for you, but maybe it's an option.

Take a look:

```
var previousImg = null;

function updateImage() {

  var d = new Date();
  var h = d.getHours().toString();
  var m = d.getMinutes().toString();

  if (h < 10) h = '0' + h;
  if (m < 10) m = '0' + m;

  var img = h + m + '.jpg';

  if (previousImg !== img) {
    var el = document.getElementById('yourImgElementId');
    el.src = '/to/your/path/' + img;
    previousImg = img;
  }
}

updateImage(); // call the first time
setInterval(updateImage, 20 * 1000); // update each 20 seconds
```

Comment: Thanks. Your code makes a lot more sense and looks cleaner. I just can't make it work. It must be me, missing or misplacing something. I'll keep trying (sorry, just starting with JS).